# Integrated camera

Tags: webcam, camera

My integrated webcam is not detected by Ubuntu 18.04.
Cheese indicate the message hereafter.
I have a Fujitsu lifebook A Series.

[image]

> ** Message: cheese-application.vala:211: Error during camera setup: No device found
>
> (cheese:7618): cheese-CRITICAL **: cheese_camera_device_get_name:
>   assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed
>
> (cheese:7618): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion
>   'string != NULL' failed
>
> (cheese:7618): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_key_type_check:
>   assertion 'value != NULL' failed
>
> (cheese:7618): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion
>   'value != NULL' failed
>
> (cheese:7618): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_set_value: key
>   'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of
>   type '(null)' was given
>
> ** (cheese:7618): CRITICAL **: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion
>   'device != NULL' failed

[image]

```
    cristi@cristi-LIFEBOOK-A557:~$ sudo lsusb -v | grep Camera
[sudo] password for cristi: 
cristi@cristi-LIFEBOOK-A557:~$ sudo lsmod | grep uvc
cristi@cristi-LIFEBOOK-A557:~$ sudo lsusb -v

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         3 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0003 3.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            4.15
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 4.15.0-29-generic xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:14.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           31
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
        bMaxBurst               0
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength              12
  bDescriptorType      42
  nNbrPorts             6
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  bHubDecLat          0.0 micro seconds
  wHubDelay             0 nano seconds
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 2: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 3: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 4: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 5: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 6: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength           15
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x02
      Latency Tolerance Messages (LTM) Supported
    wSpeedsSupported   0x0008
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   3
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat         512 micro seconds
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.01
  bDeviceClass          224 Wireless
  bDeviceSubClass         1 Radio Frequency
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Bluetooth
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x8087 Intel Corp.
  idProduct          0x0a2a 
  bcdDevice            0.01
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          177
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0000  1x 0 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0000  1x 0 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0009  1x 9 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0009  1x 9 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       2
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0011  1x 17 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0011  1x 17 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       3
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0019  1x 25 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0019  1x 25 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       4
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0021  1x 33 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0021  1x 33 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       5
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0031  1x 49 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0031  1x 49 bytes
        bInterval               1
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength           12
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000002
      Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x046d Logitech, Inc.
  idProduct          0xc534 Unifying Receiver
  bcdDevice           29.01
  iManufacturer           1 Logitech
  iProduct                2 USB Receiver
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           59
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 RQR29.01_B0016
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower               98mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      59
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     177
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0014  1x 20 bytes
        bInterval               2
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            4.15
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 4.15.0-29-generic xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:14.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           25
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength              11
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts            12
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
    TT think time 8 FS bits
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x00 0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff 0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0103 power enable connect
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
   Port 3: 0000.0100 power
   Port 4: 0000.0100 power
   Port 5: 0000.0100 power
   Port 6: 0000.0103 power enable connect
   Port 7: 0000.0100 power
   Port 8: 0000.0100 power
   Port 9: 0000.0100 power
   Port 10: 0000.0100 power
   Port 11: 0000.0100 power
   Port 12: 0000.0100 power
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered


cristi@cristi-LIFEBOOK-A557:~$ sudo modprobe uvcvideo
[sudo] password for cristi: 
cristi@cristi-LIFEBOOK-A557:~$ journalctl -b0 | grep uvc
aug 07 09:42:09 cristi-LIFEBOOK-A557 sudo[4328]:   cristi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/cristi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/modprobe uvcvideo
aug 07 09:42:09 cristi-LIFEBOOK-A557 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
cristi@cristi-LIFEBOOK-A557:~$ mplayer -cache 128 -tv driver=v4l2:width=640:height=480 -vo xv tv://
MPlayer 1.3.0 (Debian), built with gcc-7 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing tv://.
Cache fill:  0.00% (0 bytes)   

TV file format detected.
Selected driver: v4l2
 name: Video 4 Linux 2 input
 author: Martin Olschewski <olschewski@zpr.uni-koeln.de>
 comment: first try, more to come ;-)
v4l2: unable to open '/dev/video0': No such file or directory
v4l2: ioctl set mute failed: Bad file descriptor
v4l2: 0 frames successfully processed, 0 frames dropped.


Exiting... (End of file)
```

Comment: Please post the results of `lsusb -v | grep Camera` and `lsmod | grep uvc`.  If you don't see anything the first one, please post the entirety of `lsusb -v`.

Comment: Done in the question text

Comment: You should state the complete laptop model and maker, I'm assuming it's the Fujitsu LifeBook A557 , but please state this at the beginning of your question. Also, please run the commands requested by @MartinW with *sudo*.

Comment: Hm.  I agree with @Leo: I should have explicitly said do those commands as root (i.e. with `sudo`).  But, I don't see any evidence of a webcam on the bus.   Please check the bios to make sure that camera is enabled.

Comment: Question updated with sudo. The PC had initially Win and the camera worked.

Comment: Yeah, well you know how it goes: the windows install had drivers from the manufacturer.  I also suggested that you check that the uvcvideo module was installed . . . did you?  E.g. `lsmod | grep uvc` and `journalctl -b0 | grep uvc`.

Comment: No result for any of the 2 lines `cristi@cristi-LIFEBOOK-A557:~$ sudo lsmod | grep uvc
[sudo] password for cristi: 
cristi@cristi-LIFEBOOK-A557:~$ journalctl -b0 | grep uvc
cristi@cristi-LIFEBOOK-A557:~$ `

Comment: Okay, please try `sudo modprobe uvcvideo` if you would, and do `journalctl -b0 | grep uvc` afterward.  If that doesn't work, I would try to force v4l layer using the command `mplayer -cache 128 -tv driver=v4l2:width=640:height=480 -vo xv tv://`.  You may need `sudo install mplayer`, if you don't have that package already.

Comment: Also, double check in the **Software & Updates** repos of Ubuntu if you have enabled **universe**, **restricted** and **multiverse** repositories, as your laptop drivers might be proprietary. Update/upgrade apt-get later and reboot just in case.  Then look at the **Additional Drivers** tab in the same Software & Updates app, in case the webcam appears there.

Comment: @Martin Output updated in question text

Comment: @Leo 'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources. Same thing for the other 2.

Comment: This is nuts.  Are you sure that the camera is enabled?  E.g. even if it's enabled in the bios, you many need Fn+F12 to turn it on.

Comment: Tried Fn+F12, no effect

Comment: Look at your drivers for the laptop, and check what camera is the webcam. Maybe with the information from the windows drivers we might get to something.

Answer (score 0):

User on [similar platform](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10464/camera-and-cheese-not-working) with the same error messages reported that problem went away after an upgrade. So you can try:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

---

On a [different platform](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/webcam-not-working-with-cheese-unless-sudo-ed/44724/4) user said `sudo cheese` had to be used to make it work. In the end OP converted to `uvc` which was a better webcam app.

Comment: Already tried, no result.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>FN</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> on a Lifebook A557 switches your camera on.

I had the same problem. After I switched it on, I was able to use the camera.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1177853)

Comment: @Thunderbird Searching for a Lifebook A557 I found it has a camera which enables/disables with FN-F12.