# issue accessing webcam from guest in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04, webcam

[image: Cheese unable to play video from webcam]

- Host - 20.04
- Guest - 18.04
- VirtualBox - 6.1.6_Ubuntu r137129

**Webcams**

- Integrated webcam : Lenovo EasyCamera
- USB webcam : Webcam C170

**Tried:**

1. Installing guest addition
2. Updating and upgrading
3. Adding user to vboxgroup
4. Installing guvcview, ffmpeg, cheese
5. ``` sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-``uname -r ` ```

**logs from the guest**

`dmesg|grep uvcvideo`

```
6.170158] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Webcam C170 (046d:082b)
6.277828] uvcvideo 1-2:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
6.277830] uvcvideo 1-2:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 6 was not initialized!
6.277830] uvcvideo 1-2:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
6.292313] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Lenovo EasyCamera (174f:14e8)
6.576261] uvcvideo 1-3:1.0: Entity type for entity Realtek Extended Controls Unit was not initialized!
6.576262] uvcvideo 1-3:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
6.576263] uvcvideo 1-3:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
6.576264] uvcvideo 1-3:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
6.577563] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

`ls /dev/video`:

```
/dev/video0  /dev/video1  /dev/video2  /dev/video3
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 174f:14e8 Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. Webcam C170
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub6.170158]
```

`lsmod | grep uvc`:

```
uvcvideo               94208  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       45056  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              200704  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
media                  53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
```

`sudo lsusb -v |grep Camera`:

```
iProduct                1 Lenovo EasyCamera
iConfiguration          4 USB Camera
iFunction               5 Lenovo EasyCamera
iInterface              5 Lenovo EasyCamera
wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
```

`journalctl -b0 | grep uvc`:

```
May 06 17:01:53 eyebies-VirtualBox kernel: uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Webcam C170 (046d:082b)
May 06 17:01:54 eyebies-VirtualBox kernel: uvcvideo 1-2:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
May 06 17:01:54 eyebies-VirtualBox kernel: uvcvideo 1-2:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 6 was not initialized!
May 06 17:01:54 eyebies-VirtualBox kernel: uvcvideo 1-2:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
May 06 17:01:54 eyebies-VirtualBox kernel: uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Lenovo EasyCamera (174f:14e8)
May 06 17:01:54 eyebies-VirtualBox kernel: uvcvideo 1-3:1.0: Entity type for entity Realtek Extended Controls Unit was not initialized!
May 06 17:01:54 eyebies-VirtualBox kernel: uvcvideo 1-3:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
May 06 17:01:54 eyebies-VirtualBox kernel: uvcvideo 1-3:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
May 06 17:01:54 eyebies-VirtualBox kernel: uvcvideo 1-3:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
May 06 17:01:54 eyebies-VirtualBox kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
May 06 18:55:00 eyebies-VirtualBox sudo[8787]:  eyebies : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/eyebies ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/modprobe uvcvideo
```

**Cheese**

```
Failed to allocate required memory.: gstv4l2src.c(658): gst_v4l2src_decide_allocation (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin18/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src1:
Buffer pool activation failed
```

**related posts**

1. [Integrated webcam not working after upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062331/integrated-webcam-not-working-after-upgrade-to-18-04)
2. [My integrated webcam is not detected by Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002722/integrated-camera)

Comment: Are those info and log-files from host or guest ?

Comment: all the output is from the guest

Answer (score 1):

I re-installed the extension pack, selected xHCI USB controller instead of the OHCI. Both the webcams (integrated and USB) work!